# Java refer static reference to non-static method

Tags: java, android, static

I was having some problem when trying to refer static reference to non static method in Android Java. Basically from my detail class when my button onClick, it will execute the logintoFacebook() in another class:

```
ivFacebookShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){
        AndroidFacebookConnectActivity.loginToFacebook();
    }
});
```

In my AndroidFacebookConnectActivity class:

```
public static void loginToFacebook() {

    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

    if (access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
    }
    if (expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }
    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" }, new DialogListener() {

            public void onCancel() {
            }

            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                // Function to handle complete event
                // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                editor.commit();
            }

            public void onError(DialogError error) {
            }

            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
            }

        });
    }
}
```

However, I am getting error message at `getPreferences`: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getPreferences(int) from the type Activity

and `facebook.authorize(this,`: Cannot use this in a static context

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: pass Context to static method

Comment: And I ma getting this error message after passing context to static method: The method getPreferences(int) is undefined for the type Context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `Context` object to your method `loginToFacebook()` and use it to get access of `getPreferences()`

like

```
public static void loginToFacebook(Activity activityContext) {
    mPrefs = context.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    // ....... add your code here..
}
```

Where you can call this method like

```
AndroidFacebookConnectActivity.loginToFacebook(getActivity()); // If calling from fragment
```

And if calling from Activity

```
AndroidFacebookConnectActivity.loginToFacebook(ActivityName.this);
```

Comment: static method and class always remain in memory still you are using static, strange.! This will not release memory and can cause bad performance.

Comment: I am getting this error message: The method getPreferences(int) is undefined for the type Context

Comment: :) If you are an Android developer, this is strange that you are trying to force to use non-static methods. Android always suggest you to do not create an object of your class if you can make static of your method. :)

Comment: @PankajKumar can you provide some `developer.android` link for your sentence ?

Comment: @SilentKiller Yes I can but if you will not be too ironic.

Comment: @PankajKumar Sorry but my button onclick class itself was a fragment instead of Activity. So how should I do this?

Comment: @PankajKumar according to SO reputation I am toooooo junior to you I can't be ironic. please provide some links.

Comment: @IWasSoLost You can get Activity object into fragment as getActivity(). I updated the answer you can check that.

Comment: @PankajKumar don't forget to provide that link.

Comment: @SilentKiller :) knowledge can not be messured into points. So it does not mean that you have less knowledge than me. Read at http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#ObjectCreation.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is you are using `getPreferences()` which is an non-static method while you're using that method inside a static method `public static void loginToFacebook()`

Its not allowed to use any non-static method inside static method. You need to remove static modifier from `loginToFacebook()` method.

Try Like this :

```
public void loginToFacebook() {
    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Add your code here.
}
```

Comment: If I removed the static, when the onclick listener in another class cannot access it

Comment: You can create an instance of that class where you had set `onClickListener()` and you can use that method.

Comment: Sorry but would you mind to provide me with an example?

Comment: First thing connection methods are kind of utility methods you need to add them in utility class instead of Activity class.

Comment: But I followed it from this tutorial:http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/